# add a custom id parameter in the curl command

Tags: django, rest, shell, curl

I want to let my users include a custom "id" parameter in the curl command. I can't seem to get this to work for some reason. Here is the current curl command.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/Users/name/desktop/test.json http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

After I pass this parameter to my curl command, how would I access the passed in value in my django function. For reference, this is what my django function header looks like:

```
def train_view(request):
```

Comment: Can you clarify how is the custom "id" paramters passed into curl ?

Comment: that's what i'm trying to figure out. how would i pass this parameter in and then get it in django?

Comment: Can you share the test.json file (or a subset of it) ?